# Is parksavers.com legit?

Tags: tickets, disney

I'm looking for Disneyworld tickets, and I found this website: https://parksavers.com

Their prices are lower than other well-known resellers. At least, they have two years working. I found good reviews on yelp.com, but they are just a few. Do you have any experience with this website? Is it legit?

Is parksavers is a scam or not? There are a lot of well-known resellers but their prices are similar to Disney. At first, I thought they were a scam, but looking for reviews, I found they have good ones, but then again reviews can be faked.

I wrote to Disney Customer Support, and they replied

> Literally thousands of travel agencies, tour companies, and other
> outlets offer Walt Disney World® vacation packages and Theme Park
> Tickets worldwide. Please understand that, given the sheer number of
> agencies involved, we have no way to maintain an accurate listing of
> all legitimate third-party outlets.
>
> We suggest that you contact the Better Business Bureau or Chamber of
> Commerce local to the company you are inquiring about for further
> assistance.

That doesn't help me know if it's a scam or not.

Comment: They have a A+ rating at the Better Business Bureau with no complaints logged FWIW - http://www.bbb.org/utah/business-reviews/travel-agencies-and-bureaus/vacationeer-travels-llc-in-springville-ut-22309273

Comment: What do you mean by "legit"? Giving good deals? Or are you asking whether it's a scam or not?

Comment: How do we know the "Better Business Bureau" is legit? :p

Comment: @Mooz They [used to be pretty awful](http://business.time.com/2013/03/19/why-the-better-business-bureau-should-give-itself-a-bad-grade/) but they've gotten a lot better recently. Now the problem is more one of  unscrupulous companies that know how to game the BBB's system.

Comment: @Fiksdal  I updated my question.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz so that would still mean that the company can be a scam, even if they are on BBB...

Comment: Assuming that this website is not making a loss on each transaction, ask yourself how they can sell provide you with tickets that are apparently cheaper than Disney's own tickets. Are tickets available (far) in the future that are such a price via an official reseller? The fact that there are only a few reviews make it sound like me that it is too risky for this site to buy a ticket that they potentially can't sell with a profit to someone else. Meaning either a scam towards you, or a scam towards the park (e.g. credit card fraud).

Comment: There are actually many, many resellers of Disney tickets, and most of them sell cheaper than Disney themselves. It's all about what price they can get from Disney, and how much profit they want to make. Just being cheaper than Disney is certainly not an indication of being a scam.

Answer (score 7):

Vacationeer Travels on [BBB](http://www.bbb.org/utah/business-reviews/travel-agencies-and-bureaus/vacationeer-travels-llc-in-springville-ut-22309273/) includes *Business started: 08/17/2011 in UT* and *No complaints filed with BBB*.

[Dean Gibbons](https://www.linkedin.com/in/dean-gibbons-4a387372) on LinkedIn.

Seven 5* and one 4* (no other) reviews on [yelp](https://www.yelp.com/biz/park-savers-orem-2).

[Trip Advisor](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g29092-i65-k9451340-Anyone_have_experience_with_Park_Savers-Anaheim_California.html) includes:

> We have used park savers twice now, once in 2014 and again in 2015 we had no problems either time. I would not hesitate to use them again on our next trip which unfortunately wont be until 2017 as we will be taking 2016 off this year.
>
> ParkSavers is an affiliate of Ares, in fact when you click to purchase it will state that ticketing will be handled by Ares. You can find hundreds of posts online from happy customers including longtime TA members and Disboard veterans... what none of the naysayers has done is to find just one post from someone who was "scammed".
>
> Their facebook page has been up for over 5 years and has 27,000 likes. Come on now, give them a break already. Honest businesses like this don't need negative feedback from people who haven't even used them.

Bad news travels farther and faster than good and in coming across the above I noted no adverse comments.

Answer (score 0):

Parksavers worked great for me.  I was super impressed with the experience at Parksavers.  I used them about a week ago and it went smoothly. I had my tickets emailed to me immediately and saved a bunch of money as well for my whole family.  I hadn't been to Disney in quite sometime so I was able to get some tips from their website and best practices.  I would use them again.

Answer (score -3):

They aren’t really a travel agency. They just have links to real ones. We thought we were buying a Disneyland package through them and did end up buying a hotel and tickets through an external website. But it wasn’t the package that was advertised. The site they directed us to, Undercover Tourist, says they are a scam

Comment: I don't understand, parksavers directed you to another site, and the other site said parksavers were a scam?